# With clojure read/read-string function, how do i read in a .clj file to a list of objects

Tags: clojure, s-expression

As titled, If I do

```
(read-string (slurp "somefile"))
```

This will only give me the first object in the file, meaning if "somefile" is as below:

```
(a obj) (b obj)
```

Then I only get (a obj) as the result.

How do i get a list of all objects, like this?

```
((a obj) (b obj))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
(defn read-all
  [input]
  (let [eof (Object.)]
    (take-while #(not= % eof) (repeatedly #(read input false eof)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually wrap stuff in a list,

```
(read-string (str \( (slurp "somefile")  \)))
```

Comment: Ya, i end up doing this as well, be aware to add a \n before \), if the last line is a comment, this will get you out of it.