# Cannot load and compile external clojure file

Tags: clojure, compilation, load, libraries

I'm trying to load and/or compile a .clj file from within another .clj file.
I'm doing this because the file I'm trying to load just contains a bunch of maps, and I intend eventually to replace these with an xml file.  I could just `:use` the file and it'll work, but I'm trying to go through the exercise of loading an external bunch of data.

Through some random hacking around the repl (via emacs etc) I was able to `(load "default_libs")` as well as `(compile...)` it somehow (using different combinations of namespace qualifiers, `'`, and `"`) and get access to the maps, but after restarting the repl it didn't work any more, and anyway I had to use the full namespace name to get to the data.

This is lib_manager.clj:

```
(ns mycad.lib-manager
  (:use [clojure repl]
        [mycad utils]))

(compile 'mycad.default-libs)
(println mycad.default-libs/default-symbols)
```

This is the file I'm trying to load, `default_libs.clj`.  The data here will eventually be some xml file, but I'm still pretty new at this, so for now I've just written a bunch of clojure maps directly.

```
(ns mycad.default-libs)
(def default-symbols {.... })
```

So the question is how can I load a bunch of data from a `.clj` file without really loading it into the namespace with `(ns...)` but instead treating it as a source of data using either `load` or `compile`?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `compile` in your example into a `load` as you described it earlier in your question. Then the example will work.

`compile` is used for AOT compilation of a namespace. So it is not what you need here.

In case there is just a single map defined you can use `load-file`.

```
(def default-symbols (load-file "/file/path.clj"))
```

In case the "file" is actually somewhere on the classpath or by some other non-local stream, there is `load-string`.

```
(def default-symbols (load-string (slurp (io/reader stream))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lisps are very dynamic languages. Clojure, being Lisp, allows you to do the following:

```
user=> (eval (read-string "(def a 10)"))
#'user/a
user=> a
10
```

So you can load your file e.g. with a function `read-all` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6840646/788207), and then `(eval` all forms:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io) ; for (reader ..) function
(import 'java.io.PushbackReader)
....
(doseq [f (read-all (PushbackReader. (reader "your/file.clj")))] (eval f))
```

Then if your `file.clj` contains `(def`initions only, they will be in your current namespace then you can use them as simple variables. If, though, your `file.clj` contained some namespace-changing forms (`(ns..)`, `(in-ns ..)`), then things may be complicated, because current namespace will change. If such declarations are mandatory and cannot be deleted in the file itself, you can try and filter them, `(eval`ing a form only if it is a definition.

**Update**: hm, I found out that `(eval` + `(read-all` is equivalent in some sense to `(load-file`:

```
(load-file "your/file.clj")
```

But in the case of `load-file` the namespace does not change even if there were namespace-changing commands - these namespaces are just loaded into memory, and you can refer to symbols in them as usual. It seems that this is what you need.